# Manage web farms from powershell v3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5, arr

I have been searching for a way to create new web farms add add servers to it with PowerShell.

I stumbled on this link http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/microsoft-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-7/web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell which says that you should add a snapin called WebFarmSnapin.

But this does not seem to work at all in powershell v3.0 because it only says:

> Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 3.

Does anyone know how to manage web farms in PowerShell v3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found a way to do this!

http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/automating-arr-configuration/

You can generate a script from the Configuration Editor in IIS Manager. But the funny thing is that on my Windows 7 machine I could not generate PowerShell scripts. I had to do it directly on the 2012 server.